# Restricting monomorphisms to isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Suppose we have a group/ring monomorphism $\phi: R\to S$. Then we have an isomorphism $\phi|_S :R\to \phi(S)$

So now we can find inverse of $\phi|_S=\phi|_S^{-1}: \phi(S) \to R$ irrespective of group/rings $R$ and $S$ are finite or not?

I think we can , right? Just want to be sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course. This is by definition of "isomorphism".